# Project Euler #10 in C++ (sum of all primes below two million)

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, primes, time-limit-exceeded

[Project Euler Problem 10](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10) asks for the sum of all the primes below two million.

I'm creating a list of primes and keep checking any new number for divisibility with only prime numbers. I thought it should take less time but it is going over 4 minutes. How should I approach such a problem?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

#define X 2000000

using namespace std;

list<long long> lst={2ll,3ll};

bool divideByAnyPrime(long long a)// checks if the number a is divisible by any prime in the list (lst)
{

    for( auto x:lst )
        if( a%x == 0 )
            return true;
    return false;
}

long long getNextPrime()//adds next prime number to list
{

    long long a=lst.back()+2;
    for( ; divideByAnyPrime(a); a+=2);
    lst.push_back(a);

    return a;

}


int main()
{
    long long sum=5ll;//sum of already existing elements 2 and 3
    while(lst.back()<=X)
    {
        sum+=getNextPrime();
    }
    sum-=lst.back();
    lst.pop_back();//as our list will contain one element at the last which we don't want

    cout<<"\nSum is "<<sum;

}
```

Comment: Google "sieve prime". That should give you all the necessary information

Comment: My old buddy Erastothenes can probably help you out with this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prime Number calculation bottleneck](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7195/prime-number-calculation-bottleneck)

Comment: @Casey  Our threshold for [duplication](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/8/71574) is very high.  Unless the two questions have the *same* code, they aren't duplicates.  This is so even if many of the answers will be essentially the same.  That's not to say that it is unreasonable to link to previous questions.  Just not to close new questions as duplicates of previous questions unless they are essentially exact duplicates.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The algorithm itself is nowhere as efficient as it could be, but let's focus on your implementation instead:

---

### Choosing appropriate data types

```
list<long long> lst={2ll,3ll};
```

Why bother with a `list`, and why bother with with `long long`?

Only use a `list` if you need random inserts with a cached iterator. In your case, an `vector` would have fit much better.

The datatype `long long` is also several magnitudes larger than what would have been needed. The specified maximum of 2 million even fits safely within a 32bit signed integer. Even though this probably doesn't matter much, since when you compile your code on an Unixoid 64bit system, even the basic (non-long) `int` is usually 64bit.

---

```
for( auto x:lst )
    if( a%x == 0 )
        return true;
return false;
```

Checking the complete list is complete overkill. The biggest prime factor you need to check is \$\sqrt{n}\$.  To see why, take a prime factor \$p>\sqrt{n}\$.  Since \$p\$ divides \$n\$, there exists another integer \$q=n/p\$, and \$q<\sqrt{n}\$.  Either \$q\$ is prime, or it is composite and has a smaller prime factor.  Either way, \$n\$ has a prime factor smaller than \$\sqrt{n}\$, so checking larger factors is necessary.  Note that you *do* need to include \$\sqrt{n}\$ since it could be the case that \$n\$ is the square of a prime (e.g. \$9\$ or \$25\$).

---

```
bool divideByAnyPrime(long long a);
```

While it is possible and correct to search for prime numbers this way, it's not very efficient. Divisions are a lot more expensive than multiplications, or even additions. Even if this is "only" an integer, and not a floating point type.

If you want to find large quantities of primes, either use a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to process large blocks of potential prime candidates at once, or at least use one of the many prime number heuristics to eliminate number from which you know that they are certainly non-prime.

Comment: "even the basic (non-long) int is usually 64bit" - Linux (gcc) on amd64 usually has a 32-bit int and a 64-bit long

Comment: After changing all long long to int and list to vector now my program runs in 0.57 second. I'm wondering is it mattered so much !!

Comment: @GaurishGangwar Data locality, and vector instructions. A `vector` is actually backed by a plain, compact field. Accessing neighboring elements is blazing fast, respectively the CPU can even access a whole range of elements at once by using vector instructions. A `list` on the other hand stores each single element in an individual element which is linked to the next element by an additional pointer. That's an incredible amount of additional work just to traverse a list.

Comment: Ohh, thank you again for your valuable advice.

Comment: you can even look for 'no. of primes' below 2 million on the internet and call `reserve()` over that vector with that size. Since all you're trying is to calculate it's sum, this isn't cheating but optimization process ;)

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: even better would be to use the prime number theorum and approximate the number of primes.  In C++, that would be `reserve(x/(std::log(x) -1))` after the approximation of Legendre.

Answer (score 21):

Here are a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Use a better algorithm

As already mentioned in the comments, a Sieve of Eratosthenes is going to be much, much faster than the current method.  Generally speaking, doing division is a computationally expensive operation.  For example, a simple Sieve program to solve this same problem takes 0.7 seconds on my machine, while your existing program takes almost 5 minutes (4:58.4).  However, we can still make considerable improvements without changing the basic algorithm you've already implemented.  The rest of the review concentrates on helping you improve your existing code and algorithm.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Consider improving names

I think `divideByAnyPrime` is not a terrible function name (although I'd probably call it `isComposite`), but `X` and `lst` are very poor variable names.  A good name should suggest something about what it contains.  For example, I've renamed `X` to `MAXNUM` in the next suggestion.

### Prefer `constexpr` to old-style `#define`

Rather than using a `#define` for `X` the code could use a `constexpr`:

```
constexpr long long MAXNUM{2000000};
```

The advantage is that the value has an associated type.

### Eliminate global variables where practical

The code declares a global variable to contain the list of primes.  Global variables obfuscate the actual dependencies within code and make maintainance and understanding of the code that much more difficult.  It also makes the code harder to reuse.  For all of these reasons, it's generally far preferable to eliminate global variables.  For `MAXNUM`, simply put it at the top of `main`.  For the list of primes, use the next suggestion.

### Encapsulate functions and data within a class

Since you're writing in C++, I'd suggest making a class.  Here's the class declaration:

```
class Primes final : public std::list <long long>
{
public:
    Primes()
        : std::list<long long>{2,3}
    {
        for (auto n = back()+2; n <= MAXNUM; n+=2) {
            if (isPrime(n)) {
                push_back(n);
            }
        }
    }
private:
    static constexpr long long MAXNUM{2000000};
    bool isPrime(long long a) const;
};
```

Notice that `MAXNUM` is now a member of the `Primes` class and that the function `isPrime` is used instead of `divideByAnyPrime`.  Its sense is also inverted such that it only returns `true` if the passed number is prime.

### Think carefully about the mathematics

Within the routine that check for divisibility by any existing prime, there's no need to go all the way to the end of the array.  If a number \$N\$is composite, its smallest factor must be \$\le \sqrt{N}\$.  This suggests that one way to write an `isPrime` function would be this:

```
bool Primes::isPrime(long long a) const
{
    long long sqrta = std::sqrt(a);
    for (auto it = ++begin(); *it <= sqrta; ++it) 
        if( a % (*it) == 0 )
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Note that this also skips the first item in the list, which we know is `2`.

### Use standard functions

Calculating the sum is actually easily done using a standard generic algorithm:

```
int main()
{
    Primes primes;
    long long sum = std::accumulate(primes.begin(), primes.end(), 0ll);
    std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << "\n";
}
```

### Results

With all of these changes, the time drops to 1.14 seconds on my machine, which is a considerable improvement over the original 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you @Edwards Now I can see that I've used C++ in C style. You've used it in proper object oriented way. 

Comment: On my machine, it is faster as I've written it.  Any proposed optimization should be tested to make sure it really does create an improvement; the changes I showed were all actually tested and measured as shown in the answer.

Comment: If this answer only had your bold titles it would still be a great answer. Wish you did code reviews at my job back when I was a programmer.

Comment: I would like to note that it will be dangerous to use `list<>*` to call the destructor of `Primes`.

Comment: @Olzhas: One could either make the class `final` or write a virtual destructor if that were a concern.  My advice: "don't do that."

Comment: @Edward, I'm not saying something is wrong, just to note that one shouldn't try to use the class as if it was polymorphic. Great answer.

Comment: It should not only not be treated as polymorphic, but not even as a `std::list` in general. The publicly visible methods inherited from `std::list` grant the calling site access to non-`const` iterators and other interfaces. You should have implemented `begin()` and `end()` explicitly, returning constant iterators instead of exposing the backing container like this.

Comment: @Ext3h: No, the point to implementing it this way is to have a specialization of `std::list` that populates the list with a set of prime numbers.  Since the list is fully populated via the constructor, the user is free to use all `std::list` member functions on the result.